# Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree in this simple provider error in this provider example

Tags: flutter, provider

So i'm kinda playing around with the provider package and everything to get an idea of how to use it , My code is :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
      create: (context) {
        return Data();
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: MyText(),
          ),
          body: Level1(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Level1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Level2(),
    );
  }
}

class Level2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      MyTextField(),
      Level3(),
    ]);
  }
}

class Level3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(Provider.of<Data>(context).data);
  }
}

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(Provider.of<Data>(context).data);
  }
}

class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (newString) {
        Provider.of<Data>(context).changeString(newString);
      },
    );
  }
}

class Data extends ChangeNotifier {
  String data = 'starting value';

  void changeString(String newString) {
    data = newString;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

as far as i understand , i created the provider with type data , classes Level 3 and MyTextField and MyText all use it , My TextField basically just changes the value of the other 2 classes ( MyText and MyTextField) to whatever input it gets

the full error i'm getting is :

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while calling onChanged:
Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.

This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.

To fix, write:
Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false);

It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the
event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.

The context used was: MyTextField
'package:provider/src/provider.dart':
Failed assertion: line 265 pos 7: 'context.owner!.debugBuilding ||
          listen == false ||
          debugIsInInheritedProviderUpdate'
```

but it's not getting me anywhere

Answer (score 1):

This Error is Because we can't pass Listen outside the Widget tree in **Provider**.
Change this

```
   onChanged: (newString) {
        Provider.of<Data>(context).changeString(newString);
      },
```

to this

```
  onChanged: (newString) {
    Provider.of<Data>(context,listen:false).changeString(newString);
  },
```

[The Error Also Explaining the solution. Click Here to see Error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3n3i.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution which is setting the on changed fromthis

```
   onChanged: (newString) {
        Provider.of<Data>(context).changeString(newString);
      },
```

to this

```
  onChanged: (newString) {
    Provider.of<Data>(context,listen:false).changeString(newString);
  },
```

and i think that works because the method itself doesn't need to listen to the changes just make the changes , i think , feel free to correct me

Answer (score 0):

in the recently versions of dart you must add `listen: false` parameter to your `of` method.
there is the solution of your problem:
change this code:

```
onChanged: (newString) {
  Provider.of<Data>(context).changeString(newString);
},
```

to this:

```
onChanged: (newString) {
   Provider.of<Data>(context,listen:false).changeString(newString);
},
```